# How to use MySql to get High Speed Performance?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I am currently working on **MySql** database, on which we handle a very big amount of data. Many times we match and delete duplicate or inappropriate data from database, but it takes very long time to execute (sometimes 2 or 3 days).

I want to know about, if there is any method with which we can improve the speed of query execution and get result fast.

Please Suggest.

For Example:

There are two tables, First table has 1 Million records and second table also has 1 Million.

We are matching both tables and deleting data from second table if Match.

That's it.

Comment: well you could put a unique index on there to stop the duplicates from occurring in the first place

Comment: Most database engines are capable of great performance if used in a way that they prefer. I think you would be better outling what problem you have with deletes and mysql

Comment: There is no problem with MYSQL, I just want to speed up query execution.

Comment: MySql, while  great value for the money, does not have the kind of modern top-of-the-line statistical optimizer that you will find in any of the leading commercial DBMS's.  These should give you a performance speed-up with very little code & data changes.  The big three of these are: Oracle, IBM DB2 and Microsoft SQL Server (I also hear good things about Postgres, but I cannot confirm that personally).  Any of these should meet your requirements.

Comment: You should prevent the incorrect and duplicates from ending up in the database in the first place (eg using constraints, or proper checks before inserting), instead of tackling this the other way around. That said, I don't see how deleting records from tables with 1 million records would take days (I'd even be surprised if it took minutes).

Comment: 1 million is just an example. :), and not only deleting matching records from different tables also.

Answer (score 2):

Its kind of a huge question "How to delete faster".

Without any specific description I can advise you to use [UNIQUE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) in your tables to prevent duplication.

If you want an advice about some other DB, then **maybe** you could switch to some type of no-sql database like [Redis](http://redis.io/), which is incredibly fast, but you need to understand how and where to use it to get most profit from it.

Do you have indexes on the tables you're deleting from?

Do you use any kind sharding?

What engine is used in your tables?

What Mysql version do you use?

Did you try ["EXPLAINing"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) your delete query?

"As of MySQL 5.6.3, EXPLAIN provides information about SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE statements. Before MySQL 5.6.3, EXPLAIN provides information only about SELECT statements."

**EDIT**

After you added your example of deleting while comparing 2 tables:

I'd still suggest using "explain" and telling us if you use indexes or not.

But anyway instead of straight up "DELETE FROM ..." you could insert into temp table and renaming it afterwards. Like so:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE yourtable;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT <your required data from 2 tables>;
RENAME yourtable TO deleteme, tmp TO yourtable;
DROP TABLE deleteme;
```

Altough I dont like such workarounds and I'd probably refactor your architecture first.

Comment: First you select data you need for your second table, then you insert it into temp table, then you DELETE your original second table. Then you rename temp table to second's table original name. Second table will change, but without any "delete from ..." queries. Thats the point of this approach